How to save latitude and longitude into a string
how can i save latitude and longitude values in a string?
We have multiple latitude and longitude points in a table, like this
 Latitude(Number)    Longitude(Number)      

row1 55.868615380148015 9.74040663751461
row2 54.68809576270874  9.034079766165377
row3 54.948771313360766 9.936811045579077
roe4 55.78587662298497  8.807485699208513
there are more rows, this one has 4 the others can have 5 or 50 or 200
so how can i save this in a extra column, column name is (layerstring)(CLOB)
:P400_STRING has the value from the layerstring column
this string is used for a:
INSERT INTO site_map_layer (layerid,name,location) VALUES(
2,
'testlayer',
SDO_GEOMETRY(
2003,  -- two-dimensional polygon
NULL,
NULL,
SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1), -- one polygon (exterior polygon ring)
SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(:P400_STRING)
)
);

This is a Spatial question. Would this work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69542700/oracle-spatial-question-can-sdo-ordinate-array-be-populated-using-query-results

all the cordinates are not saved i one column, they are saved i separatet rows and columns

Okay, but you're still probably going to have to use PL/SQL to construct the sdo_ordinate_array collection. Rather than use the constructor, which is meant for small instantiations, loop through your values using a for cursor in PL/SQL and extend-and-add each number iteratively to the collection, or bulk collect cursor output into the collection. Either way is going to use PL/SQL. I'm not personally very familiar with Spatial, but in general this is how to work with collection types.

Whatever you do is only possible if you have a way to order your points in the proper sequence. From what you show, you do not have that.

And I assume also that you have points for multiple spatial objects. You also need to identify those. So your rows should look like: (object_nr, point_nr, longitude, latitude)

yes there are other rows, read the next answer

so how can i make a loop on the tables longitude,latitude and save the results in a array so they can be saved with this insert: INSERT INTO site_map_layer (layerid,name,location) VALUES( 2, 'testlayer', SDO_GEOMETRY( 2003, -- two-dimensional polygon NULL, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1), -- one polygon (exterior polygon ring) SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(my_array) ) );

ok now i have added more columns:
CREATE TABLE "MAP_LAYER"
(    "LAYERSEQID" NUMBER DEFAULT "DATADEV"."MAP_LAYER_SEQ"."NEXTVAL",
"LAYERID" NUMBER,
"SID" NUMBER,
"NAME" VARCHAR2(200 CHAR),
"LATITUDE" NUMBER,
"LONGITUDE" NUMBER,
"LOCATION" "SDO_GEOMETRY",
"LAYERSTRING" CLOB
)
VARRAY "LOCATION"."SDO_ELEM_INFO" STORE AS SECUREFILE LOB
VARRAY "LOCATION"."SDO_ORDINATES" STORE AS SECUREFILE LOB ;
add data to the rows:
Insert into MAP_LAYER (LAYERSEQID,LAYERID,SID,NAME,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,LOCATION) values ('10','1','200036','test','55,868615380148015','9,74040663751461',null);
Insert into MAP_LAYER (LAYERSEQID,LAYERID,SID,NAME,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,LOCATION) values ('8','1','200036','test','54,68809576270874','9,034079766165377',null);
Insert into MAP_LAYER (LAYERSEQID,LAYERID,SID,NAME,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,LOCATION) values ('11','1','200036','test','54,948771313360766','9,936811045579077',null);
Insert into MAP_LAYER (LAYERSEQID,LAYERID,SID,NAME,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,LOCATION) values ('9','1','200036','test','55,78587662298497','8,807485699208513',null);
so i think its more clear now.

It looks like two of these answers are more additions to the question. They could be added to the main question by editing.

If it is to create a polygon from a set of ordered points what you want to do, then have a look here.
